# Trouble getting data from root Vue instance with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I load all of my data in the root Vue instance and im trying to access them in my router.

How can I access the data in my root instance within my router? All the this.a.app or this.app answers i found online weren’t the solution.

**Router.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../components/login'
import Container from '../components/container'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
            path: '/login',
            name: 'Login',
            component: Login,
            props: { test: **<data from my Vue root instance>** }
        },
        {
            path: '/products',
            name: 'Container',
            component: Container,
            children: [{
                    path: 'flavor',
                    component: Login
                },
                {
                    path: 'storage',
                    component: Login
                },
                {
                    path: 'network',
                    component: Login
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

**Main.js:**

```
import router from './router’
var vm = new Vue({
el: ‘#app’,
router,
template: ‘’,
components: {
App
},
data() {
return {
modal: ‘’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid sharing the data using the router instance.
I personally like to have a store file, which contains data I want to share between my components.

```
export default {
  state: {
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

And in your component you can import the file:

```
import store from '../store'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sharedState: store.state
    }
  }
}
```

Changes to sharedState will also be passed to other components.

Source: https://skyronic.com/2016/01/03/vuex-basics-tutorial / Solution 2